# condition_variable почему не залочился в unique_lock?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, condition-variable

Есть такой пример использования condition_variable:

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable v;
bool b;

void thfunc() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    cout << "signal st" << endl;
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m);
        b = false;
        v.notify_one();
    }
}

void Run() {
    b = true;
    std::thread th(thfunc);
    th.detach();
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulock(m);
        while (b)
            v.wait(ulock);
    }

    cout << "signal recv" << endl;
    cout << "signal recv" << endl;
}
```

1) Если поставить `guard_lock` он не компилится. Зачем вариабле лок? `notify_one()` живёт же без лока.

2) Если обернуть `m.lock()` сверху то вроде работает. Но может мне повезло?

3) Поток ожидания должен был вызвать лок при создании `ulock` и не дать зайти к `v.notify_one();` и остановить его навечно. Но пример работает.

4) Для того, чтобы этот пример работал нужно 4 переменных `m, v, b, ulock` почему std не объединило их в одну?

Соответственно почему же выходят такие результаты?

Сделать пытаюсь простую вещь: поток 1 засыпает и ждёт пока поток 2 его не просигналит проснутся. Сигнал проснуться может быть послан как до того как поток уснул, так и после/во время. Может для этого есть особый вариант в std?

Comment: "Поток ожидания должен был вызвать лок при создании `ulock` и не дать зайти..." Ну так `v.wait(ulock)` ведь **снимает** лок с `ulock` на время ожидания! И тем самым "дает зайти". Азы работы condition variable кто за вас изучать будет?

Comment: "чтобы этот пример работал нужно 4 переменных m, v, b, ulock". *Глобально* нужны только `m` и `v`. `ulock` - нужна только *локально* и не обязательно. Поэтому и объединять их смысла нет. А `b` - это вы уже дописали "от себя" для вашей конкретной задачи.

Comment: "снимает лок с ulock" теперь понятно почему не зависло навечно.

Comment: ulock нужна обязательно без неё невозможно вызвать 'v.wait(ulock)' так как эта функция требует переменную.

Comment: b я, конечно, могу убрать но тогда оно перестанет работать вообще и либо: 1)зависнет 2)проснётся не вовремя. Ведь не зря же есть 'v.wait(ulock, []() {return !b; });'